# Unable to verify identity in google play developer account

Tags: google-play-console

I created Google play developer account for Organization, and I paid the 25$ , and I found out that transaction done in Payment profile already created long time ago and apparently it was created with wrong Country "Canada" and now it require to "Verify your identity" to be able to upload and publish apps, and as I understanded that means to upload the Organization owner ID and it must be from the same country as the payment profile address and it's not.

[image: Verify your identity]

And I tried to contact Google support the whole past 4 days and the Chat and Call never been enabled to use and the Email I filled the form a lot of times and I didn't get any mail to verify my request or any reply from their side.

[image: Google Support]

So any idea what should I do??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, were you able to solve your problems after 2 months?

Comment: @Delthas No not solved yet, if you found a solution please share

Comment: @AbdallahGaber how about now?

Comment: I am interested in this issue. Any solution yet please?

Comment: Hi, any solution for the same issue? I'm also trapped

Comment: This happened to me as well. Their support is basically a non-existing thing. They would never reply and even if you contact them on chat they will tell you that the chat is not the place to get help related to this. Unfortunately, you would need to create a new google account with the correct country.

Answer (score 0):

Google console will never reply and you need to try refund your amount.
Same issue happened with me i change my payment details and country but it is not working.